# Message "unknown type name 'uint8_t'" in MinGW

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I get "unknown type name 'uint8_t'" and others like it using C in MinGW.

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you include `stdint.h`?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try including `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h`.

Comment: I still get the error for uint32_t, but including stdint.h did solve the others.

Comment: For the former, to avoid a warning, `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’`, it may be required to explicitly add `include <stdio.h>` (before `#include <stdint.h>`).

Answer (score 24):

To use the `uint8_t` type alias, you have to include the `stdint.h` standard header.

Comment: To avoid a warning, `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’`, it may be required to explicitly add `#include <stdio.h>` (before `#include <stdint.h>`).

Answer (score 8):

*To be clear*: If the order of your `#include`s matters and it is not part of your design pattern (read: you don't know why), then you need to rethink your design. Most likely, this just means you need to add the `#include` to the header file causing problems.

At this point, I have little interest in discussing/defending the merits of the example, but I will leave it up as it illustrates some nuances in the compilation process and why they result in errors.

---

You need to `#include` the `stdint.h` *before* you `#include` any other library interfaces that need it.

**Example:**

My LCD library uses uint8_t types. I wrote my library with an interface (`Display.h`) and an implementation (`Display.c`).

In *display.c*, I have the following includes.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Display.h>
#include <GlobalTime.h>
```

And this works.

However, if I rearrange them like so:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Display.h>
#include <GlobalTime.h>
#include <stdint.h>
```

I get the error you describe.  This is because `Display.h` needs things from `stdint.h`, but it can't access it because that information is compiled *after* Display.h is compiled.

So move `stdint.h` above any library that needs it and you shouldn't get the error any more.

Comment: That's just poor design, `Display.h` should contain an `#include <stdint.h>`. Don't rely on the including file to include things for you. That's what header guards are here for.

Comment: That's a bit incomplete.  Can you expand or provide a reference on why includes should not be in the source file?  My includes don't provide types needed by the functions the library provides, so I wouldn't think they need to be in the header file.

Comment: As soon as you use anything from any header in any file, you just include that file in your source. I did not say you should include all the files in the header (well I did, but edited long before you answered). In my comment, I only point out how bad design it is to have to include a file before another one in order to make it work.
It wont save you any space or whatever because you will need to make this include each time before your file. If your `Display.h` needs `stdint.h`, it is not normal to not put the include directly in it.

Comment: "My includes don't provide types needed by the functions the library provides" : Your answer and the error you described said the exact opposite.

Comment: Specifically, the goal of the module is to let me use a display simply by including the 'Display.h' interface in the program.  

As no function exposed by the interface implements the 'stdint.h' library, it seems a little messy to expose 'stdint.h' by including it in the interface?  Is there a better way to avoid that?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit ? In your answer, you state "This is because Display.h needs things from stdint.h". But in your comments, you seem to be saying the opposite. When you say no function exposed uses it, then you must use it in non-exposed functions (static) ? Then why are these functions declared in your "Display.h" ?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  No function provided by 'Display.h' NEEDS 'stdint.h'.  The functions can also accept types defined in 'Display.h' itself.  

As it is not necessary for a program implementing 'display.h' to also implement 'stdint.h' I don't think it would be good to expose the 'stdint.h' library without the programmer explicitly typing '#include <stdint.h>' to do so.

Comment: Well, then you're absolutely right to do so. But I don't get why you got an error then.

Comment: http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4023876/Modular-Programming-in-C

It was a while back, but I believe this is the tutorial I followed when I was designing my libraries.

Comment: Answer is correct, but bad programming practice is offered as an example, so -1. If you get an error when you re-order your include statements, then you're not following good practices.

Comment: If there isn't an explicit `#include <stdio.h>` before `#include <stdint.h>` there may be a warning, `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to include "PROJECT_NAME/osdep.h" and that includes the OS-specific configurations.

I would look in other files using the types you are interested in and find where/how they are defined (by looking at includes).