# Simple Memory Copy (rep movs) possible error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, copy, runtime-error, memcpy

I'm trying to implement simple C/C++ language compiler dependent memcpy function.

**What are the possible erroneous results of this simple memory copy mechanism?**

(Excluding null check and the case of copying from/to same address)

The mechanism is as follows.

(1) Define structs vary by size.

```
struct S100000000Byte
{
    unsigned char pData[100000000];
};
```

(2) Cast void* argument to struct pointer, dereference the casted argument pointer, and copy.

```
__forceinline void Copy(void* _pBuffer1, void* _pBuffer0, const unsigned long long _ullSize)
{
    ...
    (*static_cast<S100000000Byte*>(_pBuffer1)) = (*static_cast<S100000000Byte*>(_pBuffer0));
}
```

Test was taken by copying buffer size of 100000000 bytes 1000 times each.

This mechanism resulted to be faster than memcpy in the following condition.

CPU : i7-10875H

IDE : Visual Studio 2019

Platform Toolset : Visual Studio 2019 (v142)

Optimization : /O2

Time performance difference was

memcpy : 6609 ms
Implemented Copy : 6547 ms

memcpy : 7062 ms
Implemented Copy : 6766 ms

so far.

Disassembly of mechanism (2) was

```
rep movs byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]
```

References were

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-memcpy/

[Implementing own memcpy (size in bytes?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876361/implementing-own-memcpy-size-in-bytes)

and articles referring about rep movsb.

Comment: Unless `_pBuffer1` and `_pBuffer0` are actually pointers to `S100000000Byte` (before they became `void*`) you have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Your structure doesn't "vary by size", it's size will always be one hundred million bytes.